# Timeout error for element already clicked

Tags: opentest

I am getting below exception even when my element has already been clicked and i am navigated to next page.

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition
>   failed: waiting for element to be clicked: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on
>   XP (56f040029c23126b0087ff1dfa82369e)] -> xpath:
>   //*[@id='login']/app-root/app-caf-login/div/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/div/div/button]
>   (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Verifying XPAth but since element is already clicked them not sure why error is coming.

**Description**: Click the Sign In Button

```
 action: org.getopentest.selenium.Click
        args:
          locator: { xpath: "//*[@id='login']/app-root/app-caf-login/div/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/div/div/button" }
```

Description: Pause for 60 second

```
action: org.getopentest.selenium.ActionsPause
        args:
          durationMs: "60000"
```

Expected : no error should be there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [timeout Exception even when element is already clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294991/timeout-exception-even-when-element-is-already-clicked)

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294991/timeout-exception-even-when-element-is-already-clicked) make sure you don't use the `sendEnter: true` argument with any of the SendKeys actions. When you pass `sendEnter: true` , the action will "press" the enter key after sending the keys to the textbox element. So basically, in the test you showed, the first action will input the username and then press enter, thus trying to log in without a password, which will of course fail.

Also, you are using the ActionsPause keyword incorrectly (more info [here](https://getopentest.org/reference/selenium-keywords.html#advanced-user-gestures-keywords)). If you want to introduce a delay in your test, you can use the [$delay()](https://getopentest.org/reference/javascript-api.html#delaymilliseconds) API, but you very rarely need to do this with OpenTest, since synchronization is built-in, meaning all test actions that perform some work on a UI element know how to wait for that element to be available before doing the work.