# timeout Exception even when element is already clicked

Tags: opentest

I am trying to click one button Sign In but even after button is clicked I am getting timeout exception.

I have verified the code and verified that I am using right locator.

description: CAP Demo
  Navigate to the GitHub website, find the React repo using the
  search functionality and go to the repo's homepage
actors:
  - actor: WEB
    segments:
      - segment: 1
        actions:
          - description: Navigate to the GitHub homepage
            action: org.getopentest.selenium.NavigateTo
            args:
              url: http://192.168.200.98:8780/CAFPortal/#/login

```
      - description: Enter Login id
        action: org.getopentest.selenium.SendKeys
        args:
          locator: {xpath: "//*[@id='login']/app-root/app-caf-login/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/input"} 
          text: ksood
          sendEnter: true

      - description: Enter password
        action: org.getopentest.selenium.SendKeys
        args:
          locator: {xpath: "//*[@id='login']/app-root/app-caf-login/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/input"}
          text: Acs@2018
          sendEnter: true

      - description: Pause for 60 second
        action: org.getopentest.selenium.ActionsPause
        args:
          durationMs: 60000

      - description: Display a greeting dialog box in the browser
        action: org.getopentest.selenium.ExecuteScript
        args:
        script: 
          var message = "Hello World!";
          alert(message);

      - description: Click on sign in 
        action: org.getopentest.selenium.Click
        args:
          locator: {xpath: "//*[@id='login']/app-root/app-caf-login/div/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/div/div/button"}
```

Just want the last testcase to pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `sendEnter: true` argument with any of the `SendKeys` actions. When you pass `sendEnter: true` , the action will "press" the enter key after sending the keys to the textbox element. So basically, in the test you showed, the first action will input the username and then press enter, thus trying to log in without a password, which will of course fail.

The other problem is that you are using the `ActionsPause` keyword incorrectly (more info [here](https://getopentest.org/reference/selenium-keywords.html#advanced-user-gestures-keywords)). If you want to introduce a delay in your test, you can use the [$delay()](https://getopentest.org/reference/javascript-api.html#delaymilliseconds) API, but you very rarely need to do this with OpenTest, since synchronization is built-in, meaning all test actions that perform some work on a UI element know how to wait for that element to be available before doing the work.